# how to control the decimal points in r, during the whole process

Tags: r, function, decimal

how can I control the decimal point in r?
Not only for printing but all the process.

options(digits=3) do not seems to work, because
some of my statistics are 1000.9844 like this and
some of my statistics are 0.3939 like this.
I want to round it to the 4th digit, but
if i use options(digits=4),
1000.9844 would be 1000.

Comment: You could only completely control the number of decimal digits of an R double by converting to a character value with sprintf or formatC. Look at ’round’ for a partial solution.

Comment: `options(digits=...)` controls the *total* number of digits, not the number after the decimal point.

Comment: "Not only for printing but all the process" - not quite clear exactly what you mean by this, but it is generally recommended to not do any rounding during the calculations, only for printing the final result.  Rounding earlier can lead to accumulating rounding errors.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to round it to the 4th digit, but if i use options(digits=4), 1000.9844 would be 1000.

You can use `round(num, 4)`

Eg,

```
> round(100.1234567, 4)
[1] 100.1235
> round(0.1234567, 4)
[1] 0.1235
```

However, as mentioned in the comment by @dww, this is not good practice since it can lead to the accumulation of rounding errors.